# Ubuntu - Routing between different subnets

Tags: routing

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySjwB.png)

I was looking at the other similar questions and could not find one that matches this one.

I have an Ubuntu VM with 2 different subnets running on Hyper V.

ETH0 - IP 10.10.1.2/24 - GW 10.10.1.1 - VLAN 10 - Hyper V tagging vlan 10
ETH1 - IP 192.168.200.2/30 - VLAN 100 - Hyper V tagging vlan 100

ETH0 gateway is configured on switch core.
Router cisco has gigabit 0/0 configured with 192.168.200.1/30. The connection goes to the core switch with a VLAN defined.

You can check topology at the beginning for more information.

From Ubuntu VM I can reach the gateway 10.10.1.1 from ETH0 and can reach 192.168.200.1 from ETH1 which is ok.

I need ETH0 to be able to communicate with ETH1 and also be able to reach 192.168.200.1 that is configured in the Cisco Router.

Can you guys help on this?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using?  eth0? & eth1? instead of systemd's predictable names?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Sorry, used ETH naming to be easier lol. enp0s3 and enp0s4. My release is the last one 18.04

Comment: just added a topology at the beginning for a better view.

Comment: nobody to help ?